# Selecting the desired object from an returned response array - unknown typing in IF statement

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

Background information: working within C# .NET 2.0 with VS10.

I'm calling a webservice which gives several things back as a response, one of which are *States*. *States* is in turn an array of *State*. Each State has several properties, some nullable. I'm interested in isolating the 3rd property, **Type**. Type is of type **ObjectType**, which can be several things, one of which is "Article". This is a bit strange actually as I'm not sure what type the **ObjectType** is (custom made). At the web service interface, it is defined as "Choice of".... "", "Article", "video", etc... But when I call it and check the logs for the xml response, I see what i want written like this:

```
   <Type>Article</Type>
```

which confuses me as to What is actually contained within State.Type:

```
  -<States>
       -<State>
             <Id>1</Id>
             <Name>Personal</Name>
             <Type>Article</Type>
        </State>
        ....
   </States>
```

So I want to run through the array for each separate state (within the States) and check if it is "Article".

```
 string stateID = null;

 myWebServer.State oneoftheStates = null; 

      for (int i = 0; i < objInfo.States.Length; i++) 
      {
          oneoftheStates = objInfo.States[i];
            if (oneoftheStates.Type == "Article") //This is the problem!!!
            {
               statusID = oneoftheStates.Id; 


                break; // found it!

            }
        }
```

Now the Question:

What I should be using instead of 'Article' as "" quotes don't work, and Article by itself doens't work etc.. With the way the IF is done here, I get the error "Operator == can't be applied to operands of type ObjectType and 'char'. And also error "too many characters in character literals."

Extra info (EDIT)

```
<complexType name="State">
   <all>
      <element name="Id" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="Name" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
      <element name="Type" type="tns:ObjectType" nillable="true"/>
      <element name="Produce" type="xsd:boolean" nillable="true"/><!-- If true for layouts, output will be send if set in featurelist -->
      <element name="Color" type="tns:Color" nillable="true"/>
      <element name="DefaultRouteTo" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/><!-- default route to for this status, returned by server, no need to send as client -->
    </all>     
  </complexType>
```

Can someone help me out Please?

Comment: first we don't compare strings like this 'Article' **Wrong**, we use double quotes "Article" , second: how is it possible to compare custom type with a primitive? (of curse unless you implement operator overloading), edit your Q put ObjectType structure as simple as possible (not everything) and focus on one point

Comment: this line 'myWebServer.ObjectType stateType = oneoftheStates.Type;' will throw an nullreference exception i think.

Comment: @Star That's the problem exactly! I've tried "Article", 'Article' and Article.. all those with both "==" and "=".. it's quite frustrating!

Comment: @JordyvanEijk it's not clear what myWebServer i. it maybe a static class and then this possible, or a variable and then you're right. as matter of fact the whole sample is a mess

Comment: @SuusvdVen because it's diffrent type as i said C# is strongly typed so you cant do that

Comment: @SuusvdVen you need to tell us what "State" is
is enum, or a class , or what ?

Comment: @Star hmm.. so there is no way to select the state with the type of "Article" then? How do I solve this in another way then? JordyvanEijk there isn't really a problem with the nullreference as far as i can see at this point. The problem is trying to select the states which have a type "Article", when apparetnly i cant use it in a "if blah == "Article" " way.

Comment: @SuusvdVen just tell us what State is and i think i can help you

Comment: Where do you assign stateType?   You compare (stateType == 'Article') in a loop but you don't even assign stateType in the loop.  Do you mean oneoftheStates.type?

Comment: @Star ok sorry if it's a mess. I thought I'd sorted out all the typings. Basically States is an array of State.. and Each State has several properties ranging from strings to bools to ObjectType (which is what I want.) I'm looking in the xml, in the wsdl, in the interface.. that's all i can find (so far) about state..

Comment: good so it should have name property (i presume) of type string.
correct?

Comment: So State is a Class?   What is is type?

Comment: @Star well actually, to make things really crazy... it has type ObjectType which has "choice of" ... then a bunch of choices one of which is "Article".. gonna see if i can find it also somewhere else.. where it is defined as an element. But that's why i thought i could make it a string.. it LOOKS like a string.

Comment: found this: <element name="States" type="tns:ArrayOfState" nillable="true"/>

Comment: and something else.. look in the code above, because it won't let me paste in the comments.. too big :(

Comment: @Blam I put the type in the above code. Does that help? :)

Comment: Hmm.. Well one of the comments asked what State was. That's in the original now. It's a bit tough going trying to find the answer to one comment while others are being placed before i answer it. I DO assign the stateType which is oneofthestates.type as you Blam asked. I don't understand xml unfortunately so I don't know if State is a Class. Object type just says "", "Article" etc.. no string or anything. I don't know how to find it.. it's not in the xml as a predefined thing.. hence i think it's an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well I figured it out. When I *manually* ran the wsdl with the command prompt, I got the generated .cs code. There I could see the type which to my eyes just with interface info, wsdl from "web reference" etc and the logs.. Looked like a "string" but was an "enum" (which is a new thing for me..). Still maybe there is someone who can benefit from this..
This is the new code from the if statement which was giving me so much grief:

```
                if (oneoftheStates.Type == myWebServer.ObjectType.Article)
                {
                    statusID = oneoftheStates.Id;
                    break;
                }
```

this is what it looked like in the generated .cs:

```
public enum ObjectType {

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("")]
Item,

/// <remarks/>
Article,

/// <remarks/>
ArticleTemplate,

/// <remarks/>
Layout,

/// <remarks/>
LayoutTemplate,

/// <remarks/>
Image,

/// <remarks/>
Advert,

/// <remarks/>
AdvertTemplate,

/// <remarks/>
Plan,

/// <remarks/>
Audio,

/// <remarks/>
Video,

/// <remarks/>
Library,

/// <remarks/>
Dossier,

/// <remarks/>
DossierTemplate,

/// <remarks/>
LayoutModule,

/// <remarks/>
LayoutModuleTemplate,

/// <remarks/>
Task,

/// <remarks/>
Hyperlink,

/// <remarks/>
Presentation,

/// <remarks/>
Archive,

/// <remarks/>
Other,
```

}

Hope this helps someone else who didn't think of enum...who knows. (changed title etc to reflect this)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some beter example of your source i think this is what you want.

```
string stateId = null;

        var states = new string[] { "bla", "bla2", "bla3" };

        for (int i = 0; i < states.Length; i++)
        {
            var stateType = states[i]; // get property by doing .Type;
            if (stateType == "Article")
            {
                stateId = states[i]; // get the Id by doing .Id;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Maybe better to use a foreach instead of a for because this is easier and better to read.

Comment: I changed the stateId thing and that seems good! Thanks:) The problem is in the if statement, "Article" isn't allowed.. there must be some other way of like denoting it? I get the error with the operand == and the one with the Article. Just as Star said, there appears to be no way to do this?

Comment: Error 1 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DemoTestEditor.myWebServer.ObjectType?' and 'string'   Oh the one thing I didn't use from the code above was that assignment of the var states.. which actually would take care of that problem with the strings.. it's just i'm not sure if that would mess up the entire States input... hmm worth a try

Comment: the error is saying that the object you get back is of type ObjectType and you are trying to compare it to a string. This is not possible only if you use operator overloading on the ObjectType class and do something that will return the type you are expecting, but i think this is a third party / closed webservice?